# Meteor: how to clone a dom (read: template) element event-bindings included

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

In my code at some point I clone a dom element

```
var item = $('[item]').clone(true);
```

HTML:

```
<section item>
    {{> details}}
</section>
```

When I insert the cloned element and try to interact with it, it seems that I've lost all the event bindings. Is there a way to fix this ? Maybe it is possible to apply the template magic to this cloned dom element (just guessing here!!) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Most probably there's another way to achieve this goal.

Comment: This question is actually related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572337/javascript-css3-resize-transform-element-into-modal-overlay) question. I want to resize/transform that element into a modal overlay.

Comment: Just noticed that only the events bound to `$('[item]')` using Meteor (`Template.myTmpl.events = { .. }`) are the ones that don't work any more. The other ones (like the jquery-ui events) still work!